# How to list same contracting client with two different employers on a resume

Tags: resume

I am on H1B visa in US and working as an application development consultant in a Big company *(lets say **company A**)* for 2+ years.
For first two years i was an employer of **company B** working for **company A**. Then i decided to switch my employer due to some issues. Company A offered me to keep working for them through a different employer i.e. **Company C**.
So i am working for the same client **Company A** on the same project but i changed employer from **Company B** to **C** and got the H1B from new employer.
Now my problem is how to show that on my CV. Previously on my CV i mentioned something like:

**Company B

Client: Company A**

***Application Development Consultant .............. ( June 2012 - till date )***

**ABC**
ABC is a state-of-the-art financial management application....

Now if i use the same format most of the data will be repetitive.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This is my suggestion:

Company B (Jun 2012-Jul 2014), Company C (July 2014 - Present)
Client: Company A
Application Development Consultant
ABC

Frankly, I'd rather put:

Company A (Jun 2012-Present)
Application Development Consultant to Company A (Jun 2012-Jul 2014)
 through Company B and Company C (Jul 2014-Present)
ABC

Comment: Agreed. I would probably choose between those two forms based on which of Company A and Companies B+C provides better name recognition. Massive consulting firms? Go with first option. Small firms consulting to a massive client? Go with the second.